# Hibernate increments version on both sides of many to many association

Tags: java, hibernate, concurrency, locking, optimistic-locking

I am not sure if this is a bug or a feature. I have the following mapping for the class `Training` that has a collection holding "*requirements*":

```
<!-- unidirectional many-to-many with requirements -->
<set name="requirements" table="TRAINING_VORAUSSETZUNG"
     lazy="false" cascade="persist,merge,save-update" inverse="false">
  <key>
    <column name="`AUSBILDUNGSGANG_ID`" not-null="true" />
  </key>
  <many-to-many class="de.mlp.cu.pollux.ausbildung.Requirement" unique="false">
    <column name="`REQUIREMENT_ID`"></column>
  </many-to-many>
</set>
```

And when I add a non altered and persistent `Requirement` instance - which comes fresh from the database - to this collection, the version of both instances (*Training* and *Requirement*) get incremented. Although - technically - only the `Training` instance is dirty. Is this usual?